# C# Is it possible to get the two input textbox values in one textbox without overwriting the first input value of textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been searching this for a while but i didn't get any information about this, so i don't know if it is possible or not. Here's what i'm trying to achieve. Any suggestions there ? Thank you

Example:

- Textbox 1 input value is: HELLO and Textbox 2 input value is: WORLD
- GET the first 3 letters of HELLO: HEL (using substring)
- Textbox 3 will get HEL so the input value is : HEL
- Now is it possible to get the textbox 2 value without overwriting the first one? expected output: HELWORLD

Comment: Anything is possible but the important question is what have you tried so far?

Comment: Get whatever you want from textbox1 and textbox2; concatenate those; then set to textbox3.

Comment: Textbox3.Text = Textbox1.Text.Substring(0,3)+Textbox2.Text

Comment: @AccessDenied is it call string concatenation ?

Comment: Yes it does. And compiler optimization can even use StringBuilder in some cases.

Comment: @fuzz Well in this world anything is possible but without the concrete idea. You cannot try it :)

Comment: If you want you can post it as answer . I will accept this ,  it solved my idea. Thank you :) @AccessDenied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's possible:

```
Textbox3.Text = Textbox1.Text.Substring(0,3)+Textbox2.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it if there's a possibility that `textBox1.Text` is less than 3 characters is to use the `Take` method to take up to 3 characters from the string (treating is as an array of characters), then use `Concat` to put those characters back into a string, and finally concatenate it with `textBox2.Text`.

```
textBox3.Text = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.Take(3)) + textBox2.Text;
```

It's a little "wordy", but will prevent exceptions from being thrown if `textBox1` contains fewer than 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

sure it is possible. Just take care that the textbox has some string longer than 3 characters

```
string processedText;
            int NoOfChars = 3;
            if (textBox1.Text.Length >= NoOfChars)
                processedText = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, NoOfChars);
            else
                processedText = textBox1.Text;

            textBox3.Text = processedText + textBox2.Text
```

;